# SAS: Assign Numbers To Contents of a Variable

Tags: variables, sas, variable-assignment

I have this variable called city, and within the variable are names of cities:

```
City
New York
Chicago
Paris
London
Boston
Hamburg
**New York
London**
```

I want to create another variable called cityNumber, and this variable should go through the City variable and assign the numbers 1,2, 3 etc.

For example:

```
City                CityNumber
New York              1
Chicago               2
Paris                 3
London                4
Boston                5
Hamburg               6
**New York              1
London                4**
```

etc.

There are several cities, and they are not always in the same order.

Thank you

Comment: Sort by city and use `by` group processing. http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/62955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000761932.htm

Comment: Hi Thank you for the quick reply. My main issue is how to assign the numbers after I sort. I tried if first.city then cityNumber = 1, etc, but idoes not work.

Comment: Look into the datastep `by` and `retain` statements.

Comment: Are the asterisks in your post present in your data? Are there multiple names/values for the same city that need to be assigned the same number?

Comment: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/faq/enumerate.htm

Comment: No there are no asterisks, I wanted to bolden that part to show that the cities are spread out through the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Sort data by city, then create the `cityNumber` with the `by` groups. You want an `if` statement that increments the `cityNumber` by one at the beginning of each group. The easiest way to accomplish this is with a sum statement:

```
data want;
  set have;
  by city;
  if first.city then cityNumber+1;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you all for the help.